# React Native 0.48 - `scrollview has no proptype for native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am running into the following error after I upgraded to react native 0.48, which is showing on the expo app (**in IOS only**) when rendering

> scrollview has no proptype for native prop
>   RCTScrollView.onScrollAnimationEnd of native type BOOL .if you havent
>   changed this prop yourself this usually means that your versions of
>   the native code and javascript code are out of sync. Updating oth
>   should make this error go away.

Not sure why, But I narrowed my code base down as much as possible. this error is generated when I try to use ListView.
Here is the code base:

```
import React from 'react';
import {AppRegistry,View,Text,StyleSheet,ListView} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fullView:{
    flex:1
  },
  statusBar: {
    backgroundColor:"#de3c3c",
    padding:5
  },
});



class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData}</Text>}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

And here are my dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^20.0.0",
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.48.1",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  }
```

I took a look over the docs for ListView, seems like its deprecated, but it should still work? FlatList generates the same error as well when i tried it.

Note: I made sure there isn't another packager running .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the possible solution!

```
- Bump expo version in package.json to 21.0.2
- Bump react-native version in package.json to 0.48.4
- Remove node_modules
- npm install or yarn install
- Change sdk version in app.json to 21.0.0
```

...
ScrollView error should disappear.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be accepted, though I believe the root issue was an XCode update. Thanks!

Comment: You may also need to update `jest-expo` to `^21.0.0` https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-21-0-0-is-now-available-be33b79921b7

Comment: Thanks a ton, you saved my day.

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md it looks like expo 20.x.x should be used with 0.47.x version of react-native.

Comment: Yes but I explicitly updated to RN 0.48.* so that I can test it, and i checked in the app store, but there is no update for the Expo Client app

Comment: As seen in the versions table you cannot update RN to 0.48.* because Expo 20.x.x is only compatible with 0.47.* You have to wait until there is new version of Expo before you can update RN.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently at the moment Expo Client app not completely compatible with RN 0.48 and higher.
One solution is to use **react-native init** in order to test react native projects of version 0.48.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same question. But I have not use expo.
Finally i fix it by reset ios simulator.

Step: Hardware - Erase All Content and Settings - Reset